# Sorting an array based on multiple values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort the below array, based on multiple values, report_yr and report_qtr,
the array should be sorted according to year first and then as per quarter(for that same year).

// input array

```
let arr = [{
  report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '1'
},
{
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '3'
},
{
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '4'
},
{
  report_yr: '2017',
  report_qtr: '2'
},
{ report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '2'
}];
```

// expected output:

```
[ 
{ report_yr: '2019',
report_qtr: '4' },
{ report_yr: '2019',
report_qtr: '3' },
{ report_yr: '2008',
report_qtr: '1'
},{ report_yr: '2008',
report_qtr: '2'
},
{ report_yr: '2017',
report_qtr: '2' } ];
```

// What I am trying:

I am trying to use loadash methods for this,

```
_.sortBy(arr,
      ['report_yr', 'report_qtr']);
```

Similarly tried with orderBy but no luck so far.

Comment: why does your result ascend with `report_qtr` when `report_yr` is `2018` but when the objects with `report_yr` are `2019` the objects descend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` method and do this with plain javascript.

```js
let arr = [{"report_yr":"2008","report_qtr":"1"},{"report_yr":"2019","report_qtr":"3"},{"report_yr":"2019","report_qtr":"4"},{"report_yr":"2017","report_qtr":"2"},{"report_yr":"2008","report_qtr":"2"}]

arr.sort((a, b) => b.report_yr - a.report_yr || b.report_qtr - a.report_qtr)
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be work for you.

```
data.sort(function (x, y) {
    var n = y.report_qtr - x.report_qtr;
    if (n !== 0) {
        return n;
    }

    return y.report_yr- x.report_yr;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sort` method

```js
let arr = [{
  report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '1'
},
{
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '3'
},
{
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '4'
},
{
  report_yr: '2017',
  report_qtr: '2'
},
{ report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '2'
}]

arr.sort((b, a) => +a.report_yr - +b.report_yr || +a.report_qtr - +b.report_qtr )

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

what If you add `report_yr`  + `report_qtr` and sort descending like this

```
    arr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
        const one = parseInt(a.report_yr) + parseInt(a.report_qtr);
        const two = parseInt(b.report_yr) + parseInt(b.report_qtr);
        if (one > two) {
            return -1
        }
        return 1;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `_.orderBy` instead of `_.sortBy`. If you do not, you cannot sort descending.

This will sort the `report_qtr` descending and `report_yr` ascending. I noticed your desired output contradicts sorting though...

```js
let arr = [{
  report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '1'
}, {
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '3'
}, {
  report_yr: '2019',
  report_qtr: '4'
}, {
  report_yr: '2017',
  report_qtr: '2'
}, {
  report_yr: '2008',
  report_qtr: '2'
}];

let sortedArr = _.orderBy(arr, ['report_qtr', 'report_yr'], ['desc', 'asc']);

console.log(sortedArr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you ***really*** want that order, you can do this:

1. Find the year frequency
2. Sort by frequency
3. Sort by year
4. Check if the years are odd, sort by quarter descending
5. Check if the years are even, sort by quarter ascending
6. Fall back to sorting by quarter ascending

```js
let arr = [
  { report_yr: '2008', report_qtr: '1' },
  { report_yr: '2019', report_qtr: '3' },
  { report_yr: '2019', report_qtr: '4' },
  { report_yr: '2017', report_qtr: '2' },
  { report_yr: '2008', report_qtr: '2' }
];

const yearFreq = arr.reduce((o, i) => ({...o, [i.report_yr] : (o[i.report_yr] || 0) + 1}), {});

let sortedArray = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  let diff = yearFreq[b.report_yr] - yearFreq[a.report_yr];
  if (diff !== 0) return diff;
  let a_year = parseInt(a.report_yr, 10);
  let b_year = parseInt(b.report_yr, 10);
  diff = b_year - a_year;
  if (diff !== 0) return diff;
  let a_odd = a_year % 2 === 1;
  let b_odd = b_year % 2 === 1;
  let a_qtr = parseInt(a.report_qtr, 10);
  let b_qtr = parseInt(b.report_qtr, 10);
  if (a_odd && b_odd) return b_qtr - a_qtr;
  if (!a_odd && !b_odd) return a_qtr - b_qtr;
  return a_qtr - b_qtr;
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>

<!-- Expected

[{
  "report_yr": "2019",
  "report_qtr": "4"
}, {
  "report_yr": "2019",
  "report_qtr": "3"
}, {
  "report_yr": "2008",
  "report_qtr": "1"
}, {
  "report_yr": "2008",
  "report_qtr": "2"
}, {
  "report_yr": "2017",
  "report_qtr": "2"
}]

-->
```